# How can I use alignedat in subequations?

Tags: numbering, amsmath, align

I have a set of equations inside a `subequations` environment. **Update**: I use a macro to generate long subsubscripts in `\rm`.

```
\newcommand{\foobar}{\rm foobar}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{5}
t_{p_{\foobar}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& &\mathcal{P}_{\foobar}(e)       &&\wedge&      &\mathcal{H}_{\foobar}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
f_{p_{\foobar}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& &\mathcal{P}_{\foobar}(e)       &&\wedge& \lnot&\mathcal{H}_{\foobar}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
f_{n_{\foobar}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& \lnot &\mathcal{P}_{\foobar}(e) &&\wedge&      &\mathcal{H}_{\foobar}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
t_{n_{\foobar}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& \lnot &\mathcal{P}_{\foobar}(e) &&\wedge& \lnot&\mathcal{H}_{\foobar}(e) \big\} \big\vert
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
```

These equations have a lot of unnecessary space between columns. Using `gather` along with `alignedat`, they are aligned the way I want them - without any additional horizontal space. However, this leads to the equations being assigned only a single equation number. When I use `alignat` instead, latex adds additional space between columns - which I don't want. How can I achieve correct alignment and correct numbering?

Comment: It's not recommended to use commands such as `\rm` in formulas; the correct way is `\newcommand{\foobar}{\mathrm{foobar}}` that doesn't even require braces like in `\mathcal{P}_\foobar`, although braces don't harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `align` and `\phantom`s to get the desired alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:Classification}
  \begin{align}
  t_{p_{x}} &= \big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \mid\phantom{\lnot}\mathcal{P}_{x}(e)\wedge
    \phantom{\lnot}\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
  f_{p_{x}} &= \big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \mid\phantom{\lnot}\mathcal{P}_{x}(e)  \wedge
    \lnot\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
  f_{n_{x}} &= \big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \mid\lnot \mathcal{P}_{x}(e) \wedge
    \phantom{\lnot}\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
  t_{n_{x}} &=\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \mid\lnot \mathcal{P}_{x}(e) \wedge 
    \lnot\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Note that I also used `\mid` to get some space between the set generic elements and their defining condition.

Answer (score 2):

Please post minimal examples. I cannot see this in the following example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignedat}{5}
t_{p_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert&  
&\mathcal{P}_{x}(e)       &&\wedge&      &\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
f_{p_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& &\mathcal{P}_{x}(e)       &&\wedge& \lnot&\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
f_{n_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& \lnot  &\mathcal{P}_{x}(e) &&\wedge&      &\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
t_{n_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& \lnot &\mathcal{P}_{x}(e) &&\wedge& \lnot&\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{5}
t_{p_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& &\mathcal{P}_{x}(e)       &&\wedge&      &\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
f_{p_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& &\mathcal{P}_{x}(e)       &&\wedge& \lnot&\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
f_{n_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& \lnot &\mathcal{P}_{x}(e) &&\wedge&      &\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert\\
t_{n_{x}} &=& &\big\vert \big\{e \in E^\prime \vert& \lnot &\mathcal{P}_{x}(e) &&\wedge& \lnot&\mathcal{H}_{x}(e) \big\} \big\vert
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right. To "minimize" my example, I removed the \foobar indices that seem to cause the problem in the first place. I have edited my question to show the actual problem.

Comment: @jannik I still see no problems if pasted into my example above

Comment: Okay - then there is some weird cross-interaction of a package in my thesis. Since Gonzalo's solution fixes my problem I won't do the full bisection search to determine what exactly causes the problem. But thank you for your help.