# eqnarray with subnumber

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

When I use eqnarray

```
\begin{eqnarray}

eq\\
eq\\
eq\\

\end{eqnarray}
```

this show me

```
eq (1)
eq (2)
eq (3)
```

In some papers I see this output

```
eq (1a)
eq (1b) 
eq (1c)
```

how I can make this way ?

Comment: Duplicates: [How can I use alignedat in subequations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18596/5764), although it works the same with `align` and friends; [using subequations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14027/5764). Also, rather use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment instead of `eqnarray`. See [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`amsmath` has an environment `subequations` that will do what you want:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{eqnarray}
 eq \\
 eq \\
 eq
\end{eqnarray}
\end{subequations}
```

some observations:

- you don't want blank lines withn the scope of display math; they will result in error messages.
- you don't want `\\` at the end of the last line, or you'll end up with too much space below the display.
- it would really be better to use one of the multi-line display structures provided by `amsmath` rather than `eqnarray` (see [this article](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/) for the reasons why).

to find out what structures are provided by `amsmath`, if you have a tex live installation, type `texdoc amsmath` at a command line prompt.

Answer (score 24):

[Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen) Use the `align` environment inside the `subequations` environment from the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
      (a+b)^2 &= a^2+2ab+b^2 \\
      (a-b)^2 &= a^2-2ab+b^2  \\
      (a+b)(a-b) &= a^2-b^2 
    \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

The second look (with a, b, c ... appended to the "main" equation number) can be achieved with the `subequations` environment of the `amsmath` package. The following MWE (minimum working example) demonstrates the basic usage of this package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
c &= d\\
e &= f
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally: Don't use the `eqnarray` environment -- use the `align` environment instead. 
The `eqnarray` environment has several severe shortcomings; for a justification of this assertion see, for instance, ["\eqnarray vs \align"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Comment: shouldn't a backslash be appended to 'a &= b\', so that 'a &= b\\'?

Comment: @Kuti - Thanks. Some months ago, a site-wide bug swept thru lots and lots of postings and "converted" instances of double-backslash to single-backslash. The only apparent recovery from this bug is to hand-edit the postings to restore the instances of double-backslash. A nightmare job, honestly. (I just "fixed" this posting, BTW.)