# How to refer to "all" the equations when using subequations?

Tags: amsmath

I've just found out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40800/eqnarray-with-subnumber) I can use the `subequations` environment to have equations share a number but with a letter (1a, 1b). So now, I have

```
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
     a & = b\\
     b & = c
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

I can use labels to easily refer to eq (1a) or (1b), but how do I refer to equation (1) in its globality ?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's trivial:

```
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
     a & = b \label{eq:a}\\
     b & = c \label{eq:b}
  \end{align}
\label{eq:global}
\end{subequations}

I just have to refer to \eqref{eq:global}.
```

Comment: I'd put the global `\label` at the top, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: I think it's good to keep in mind that labels come more at the end (after \caption in figure, for instance).

Comment: I prefer to think in a different way: here you're labeling  subequations, in a figure or table you're labeling a caption. You can have two captions in the same `figure` environment; to the contrary, `subequations` is for a single number.

Comment: A little twist on this. I followed this without putting the labels (a,b) in the \align and it still worked fine. I then put an \intertext into the align and it stopped working. I put the labels back and now It works again. Sometimes you just need that rabbits foot.