# how to obtain 4 equations in 2 lines with same number but different letter

Tags: equations, numbering

i was trying to get something like this
[image: cosmographic parameters]

but everything i try gives errors,

does anyone know what's the right way? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`eqnarray` with subnumber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40800/5764)

Comment: You need to wrap an `align` environment inside a `subequations` environment.

Comment: Yes, thank you both